# Image not loading through node.js

Tags: image, canvas, craftyjs

I'm using the craftyjs library to load an image. Pretty basic.

```
Crafty.load(['TestGame/assets/16x16_forest.gif'], function () {
    // do stuff after image loaded...
```

This works fine when I run it from my file system, but as soon as I try running it from node, things start going wrong. The image is still loading fine (from looking at network activity), but the crafty library is throwing an `Uncaught TypeError: Type error` at this line

```
context.drawImage(this.img, x, y, ...)
```

I noticed the `this.img` variable is listed as type `img` in Chrome when it works from the file system, but of type `HTMLImageElement` when it doesn't work through node. Otherwise the variables are identical (other than the URL). Is there some setting I need to change in how node serves up images?

**Edit**

I tried this using ASP.NET as a backend, and I still got the same error. I also tried using a different image. I'm starting to think it's a bug in the craftyjs library.

Comment: What do you mean by "but as soon as I try running it from node"? What is node? If it is Node.js, then Crafty.js will properly not work because it has not been tested with that.

Comment: @KevinSimper It doesn't work in asp.net either. I was following [this](http://buildnewgames.com/introduction-to-crafty/) tutorial, which might just be out of date. I've since switched to limejs, which seems to be working alright.

Comment: Asp.net and Crafty.js do not really have anything together? And what guide are you following?

Comment: Well you need something server side. The link is behind the word "this" in my above comment. Posted again here -> http://buildnewgames.com/introduction-to-crafty/